# About Hom and global section functor for $O_X$ modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules, quasicoherent-sheaves

Is it true for any $O_X$-module $F$  that
$$
  Hom_{O_X}(F,O_X)\cong F(X)= \Gamma(X,F)
$$
And is it in general true that the sheafification of $F(X)$ is $F$ ? 
I think that it is true for quasi-coherent sheaves but it can be generalized at least the first part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. However we have $Hom(O_X,F) \cong \Gamma(X,F)$. For a counter-example to your equality, we have $Hom(F,O_X) = 0$ when $F$ is a skyscraper sheaf and $X$ is of dimension at least $1$.

It's not clear what do you mean by "the sheafification of $F(X)$". If $X$ is affine then the data of a quasi-coherent sheaf is equivalent to the data of its global sections. In general it's not the case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can I prove : $ Hom(OX,F)≅\Gamma(X,F)$ ? I need to construct an explicit isomorphism?

Comment: If you know how to prove that $Hom_R(R,M) \cong M$ canonically where $R$ is a ring and $M$ is a $R$-module, the proof is exactly the same here.

Comment: Ok, you're right thanks a lot!

Comment: @andres : Dear Andres, you're welcome !